# Intel CPU memory type meaning

Tags: memory, cpu, intel-core-i7, ddr

I'm reading Intel CPU's spec, the memory type it lists a single frequency, like for [i7-8809G](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/130409/intel-core-i7-8809g-processor-with-radeon-rx-vega-m-gh-graphics-8m-cache-up-to-4-20-ghz.html), it says `Memory Types: DDR4-2400`, the confusing is does this mean **only** 2400 memory modules are supported, memory modules of **at least** 2400 are supported, so 2666/3200 etc are also ok?

Comment: It means the base frequency is 2400 MHz with any other speeds being either due to overclocking or XMP profiles being use.  What speed your memory will run at will depend on the hardware

Comment: what does that mean for ram modules? when i try to buy memory modules, it is at one of the frequences, 2400/2666/3200 etc, i'd like to buy the one that are supported by the cpu and chipset.

Comment: Check your manual for your OEM laptop/desktop or your OEM motherboard.  Given the CPU is a soldered solution you would have to look to the OEM to provide specifications on the motherboard to determine compatible memory frequencies

Comment: by saying the base frequency is 2400MHz, do you mean it can go higher or lower or not?

Comment: Welcome to superuser.com! In case you find an answer to help solve a problem don't forget to click either the grey ☑ or the up-pointing arrow/triangle to the left of the text.

Answer (score 0):

General answer:

A speed indicating number, as "2400" is here, is to be taken as a lead to which type of components to use (memory modules here).

Attempting to use a **component with a lower spec** (=indicative number) may either

- just hamper the performance,
- create intermittent faults or
- fail to work entirely

... as the component cannot keep up with the machine, runs hot (e.g. due to "overclocking") or similar. It may also degrade over time, due to being used outside of it's specification.

With a **higher spec component** you're unlikely to get the benefits of the higher spec, it may also be that the higher spec component isn't "backwards compatible", so fails to work because of that.

Answer (score 0):

The memory type specification is, in every case I have encountered, the *maximum* speed supported for the interface; DDR4-2400 supports a burst rate of 2400 [MT/s](https://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/47408/mt-sec) with a clock speed of 1.2GHz.

I would *not* expect the part to support DDR4-2666, for example. A DDR4-2666 module *might* work here (no guarantees, of course) but at a rate no faster than 2400 if it does in fact operate.

In an embedded environment I have had to change parts fairly regularly on existing designs as the slower speed grades become obsolete and simply run the newer (faster capability) parts at a lower speed.

I cannot definitively state this for Intel, but every memory controller I have designed around (DDR1, DDR2, DDR3, DDR4) have supported all (JEDEC) supported speeds *up to* the maximum supported rate although those choices had various internal processor side effects.

At the *system* level, it is perfectly possible that only **one** specific memory module type is supported; there are numerous reasons for this, not least of which is processor internal clock generation and distribution.

For DDR4, the minimum rate is 1600 MT/s (clock at 800MHz) so *if* the controller is the type I have used, the part should support anything from DDR4-1600 to DDR4-2400. (Note: all DDR types have a *minimum* speed requirement that is related to the internal clock generation circuitry).

For DIMM and SO-DIMM implementations, the controller is set up by the BIOS after it has read the data from the on-board [SPD](https://integralmemory.com/faq/what-spd), unlike the embedded solutions (ICs soldered down on the PCB) I have done where I had to figure out all the timings (by hand) and add that to the init code.